# SQL Server Reporting services chart report

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

[image]I currently have a dataset with the columns `API50`, `Counter Value` and `DBName`. The values for example are something as below.

```
API50    CounterValue  DBName
34.5       1            Test1
44.5       25           Test1
34.5       42           Test1
54.5       67           Test1
34.5       76           Test1
94.5       88           Test1
14.5       99           Test1
```

I have created a chart report and selected my X axis as `CounterValue` my Y axis as `API50`.

The report is plotted correctly and my Y axis goes only upto 99.

Is there anyway I can have my X axis as 50 point increments till 600 (e.g., 0, 50, 100, 150...and so on till 600) and plot the counter value?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the sample data and description is correct? Based on your data, this will give a single straight line at value `34.5` on the **Y** Axis, and the **X** Axis will go up to 99, since `API50` is Y and `CounterValue` is X. Similarly, should all values for `API50` be exactly the same? Can you add a screenshot of your current report?

Comment: I have uploaded the image. The values mentioned in my question are dummy values, however I have edited them too. AS you can see from the image the counter value only goes upto 250 as the final counter value is 268. I want the X axis to go upto 600 however the plot will be only till 268.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a basic chart with your sample data:

[image]

Gets the same result you have described, i.e. the X Axis just goes up to the maximum `CounterValue` value or so:

[image]

You need to update the X Axis properties:

[image]

Here I've updated:

- List item
- Maximum
- Interval
- Interval Type

I've also checked the **Scalar Axis** value - this is most important otherwise the above values won't work properly.

Now you can see the change in the designer:

[image]

And the end result has your axis requirements:

[image]